# How to align the bootstrap navbar within my conatiner

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

i have a html page with fixed bootstrap navbar.i have a container of width 1000px i am trying to put this navbar inside my container but i couldn't achieve.still it occupies the entire page width.I want the fixed navbar to be aligned within my container.i have attached the snapshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OssAe.png)
    enter code here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  html,body{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    background: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
}
 #container {
    width: 1000px;
    display: table;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height:100%;
    background:#f5f5f5;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body style="height:1500px">
<div id="container">
<nav width="1000px" class="conatiner1 navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:50px">
  <h3>Fixed Navbar</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Scroll this page to see the effect</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what you want exactly I couldn't get? do you want the same width of the below container ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just removed the `navbar-fixed-top` from navbar.

Here is updated code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <style>
  html,
  body {
   font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 16px;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   font-smoothing: antialiased;
   text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
   background: #fff;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
  }

  #container {
   width: 1000px;
   display: table;
   min-height: 100%;
   margin: auto;
   height: 100%;
   background: #f5f5f5;
  }

 </style>
</head>

<body style="height:1500px">
 <div id="container">
  <nav width="1000px" class="conatiner1 navbar navbar-inverse">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Page 1</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Page 2</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#">Page 3</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container" style="margin-top:50px">
   <h3>Fixed Navbar</h3>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <h1>Scroll this page to see the effect</h1>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <nav width="1000px" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kondaldurgam/pqL8vq05/1/)

See this below example it will help

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  html,body{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    background: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
}
.conatiner1{position:fixed; width:100%}
@media (max-width:769px){
.divContent{margin-top:230px !important;}
}



  </style>
</head>
<body style="height:100%;">
<div class="container">
<nav  class="conatiner1 navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</div><div>
<div class="container divContent" style="margin-top:50px">
  <h3>Fixed Navbar</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Scroll this page to see the effect</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Just Check following  code


 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style>
      html,body{
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        font-smoothing: antialiased;
        text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
        background: #fff;
        height: 100%;
        margin:0;
    }
     #container {
        width: 1000px;
        display: table;
        min-height: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        height:100%;
        background:#f5f5f5;
    }
    nav {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1170px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body style="height:1500px">
    <div id="container">
    <nav width="1000px" class="conatiner1 navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container" style="margin-top:50px">
      <h3>Fixed Navbar</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"> 
          <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"> 
          <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>  
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h1>Scroll this page to see the effect</h1>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```